# Syncfusion DOC to PDF conversion changing the colour of my font

Tags: vb.net, pdf, syncfusion

I am converting a DOC template to PDF in vb.net using Syncfusion dll.
It is converting well but my headers are getting with black font instead of white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Word documents the font color will be considered as `Auto` if not defined and the viewer will render the text as white, if its background is filled with dark color or black its background is filled with light color. I suspect this could be your scenario here, try setting font color as white for particular header text explicitly using MS Word to resolve this issue from your end. Otherwise report this issue to Syncfusion support and get proper resolution. You can contact Syncfusion support through [this **link**](http://www.syncfusion.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2fsupport%2fdirecttrac)